# Expected value of given x for simple linear regression?

Tags: regression

I understand statisticians call the predicted y in a simple linear regression the “mean of y.” Let’s assume we only have 3 pairs of x and y values: (1,1), (2,3), (3,1). Whatever the regression line ends up being, for a value of x equal to 4 the regression line would output something representing the “mean of y given x = 4.” In what sense is this predicted y from the regression line at x = 4 the “mean of y?” It must be a guess of the mean of y at x = 4? It can’t be an “actual” mean calculated from our data. Do you see my confusion? I don’t understand why every y value on the regression line is the mean of y given whatever x is chosen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In what sense is this predicted y from the regression line at x = 4 the “mean of y?” It must be a guess of the mean of y at x = 4?

Correct.  It is an estimate of $E(Y \vert X = x)$.

> It can’t be an “actual” mean calculated from our data

Also correct.  It is an estimate of the actual mean.

Comment: Thank you! No one has clearly said this to me when asking this question, so thanks a ton. One more question if you’re willing: I am seeing depictions of “conditional distributions” of y given x for every value of x on a scatter plot with the regression line. Each y value has a normal distribution with mean equal to the predicted value given by the regression line. How can we say the regression outputs at each x represent the mean of y at that value? Isn’t that a reach given we know, in my example, only of three coordinate pairs?

Comment: @user3138766  The quality of the estimate is something the analyst has to consider.  If all you have is 3 data points, then yea I would be dubious of all estimates.

Comment: Thank you Demetri.